# PayPal error 10525 in Magento 1.9.3.10

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express

Experiencing some errors in Magento 1.9.3.10 with paypal express checkout. Full Log of the error is:

```
2020-08-20T08:00:54+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    [SetExpressCheckout] => Array
        (
            [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
            [AMT] => 24.90
            [CURRENCYCODE] => GBP
            [RETURNURL] => example.com/testing/paypal/express/return/
            [CANCELURL] => example.com/testing/paypal/express/cancel/
            [INVNUM] => 1033465
            [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Sole
            [GIROPAYCANCELURL] => example.com/testing/paypal/express/cancel/
            [GIROPAYSUCCESSURL] => example.com/testing/checkout/onepage/success/
            [BANKTXNPENDINGURL] => example.com/testing/checkout/onepage/success/
            [LOCALECODE] => en_GB
            [ITEMAMT] => 20.75
            [TAXAMT] => 4.15
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
            [BUSINESS] => 
            [NOTETEXT] => 
            [EMAIL] => email@email.com
            [FIRSTNAME] => John
            [LASTNAME] => Doe
            [MIDDLENAME] => 
            [SALUTATION] => 
            [SUFFIX] => 
            [COUNTRYCODE] => GB
            [STATE] => Example
            [CITY] => Example
            [STREET] => Example
            [ZIP] => Example
            [PHONENUM] => Example
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => GB
            [SHIPTOSTATE] => Example
            [SHIPTOCITY] => Example
            [SHIPTOSTREET] => Example
            [SHIPTOZIP] => Example
            [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => Example
            [SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
            [STREET2] => 
            [SHIPTONAME] => John Doe
            [ADDROVERRIDE] => 1
            [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [TOKEN] => EC-83G664135W4073021
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2020-08-20T08:00:54Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => cd75d4ce5851
            [ACK] => Success
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 54802995
        )

    [__pid] => 26817
)

2020-08-20T08:01:58+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    [GetExpressCheckoutDetails] => Array
        (
            [TOKEN] => EC-83G664135W4073021
            [METHOD] => GetExpressCheckoutDetails
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [TOKEN] => EC-83G664135W4073021
            [BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS] => 0
            [CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionNotInitiated
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2020-08-20T08:01:58Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => 85230dba809d9
            [ACK] => Success
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 54802995
            [EMAIL] => example@example.com
            [PAYERID] => T5TDEQRE6QCXE
            [PAYERSTATUS] => verified
            [FIRSTNAME] => John
            [LASTNAME] => Doe
            [COUNTRYCODE] => GB
            [SHIPTONAME] => John Doe
            [SHIPTOSTREET] => Example
            [SHIPTOCITY] => Example
            [SHIPTOSTATE] => Example
            [SHIPTOZIP] => Example
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => GB
            [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => Example
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United Kingdom
            [ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
            [CURRENCYCODE] => GBP
            [AMT] => 24.90
            [ITEMAMT] => 20.75
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
            [HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
            [TAXAMT] => 4.15
            [INVNUM] => 1033465
            [INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
            [SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
            [INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => false
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => GBP
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 24.90
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 20.75
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 4.15
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM] => 1033465
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0.00
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT] => 0.00
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID] => example@mysite.com
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => false
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] => John DOe
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => Example
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => Example
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => Example
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => Example
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => GB
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM] => Example
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United Kingdom
            [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
            [PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
        )

    [__pid] => 26991
)

2020-08-20T08:02:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    [DoExpressCheckoutPayment] => Array
        (
            [TOKEN] => EC-83G664135W4073021
            [PAYERID] => T5TDEQRE6QCXE
            [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
            [AMT] => 0.00
            [CURRENCYCODE] => GBP
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
            [NOTIFYURL] => example.mysite.com/testing/paypal/ipn/
            [RETURNFMFDETAILS] => 1
            [ITEMAMT] => 24.90
            [METHOD] => DoExpressCheckoutPayment
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [TOKEN] => EC-83G664135W4073021
            [SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED] => false
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2020-08-20T08:02:00Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => 83be0b90f8db
            [ACK] => Failure
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 54802995
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10525
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Data
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed. The amount to be charged is zero.
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
        )

    [__pid] => 26991
)
```

Error from exception log is:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'PayPal response hasn't required fields.' in /public_html/testing/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:996
```

As you can see during the GetExpressCheckoutDetails process the AMT amount has been set to 0.00

Please could anyone point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this issue, if anyone runs into the same error. This was actually related to a third party extension called mw_rewardpoints there was a setting (Calculate to TAX), when this was set to 'Before Redeem Points' it was causing the PayPal error. When I changed this to 'After Redeem Points' the error went away.